# Passing Data of a Row from a table component to a Form component with an edit button

Tags: angular

I'm using Angular, please can anyone help me with an example of passing Data from a row of a table component and display it in another form component using an edit button.

I tried to use a service for this, by using BehaviourSubject.

**emit.service.ts**

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EmitService {

public defaultValue : string = '';
public RowSender : BehaviorSubject<string>= new BehaviorSubject<string>(this.defaultValue);
public currentValueEmit = this.RowSender.asObservable();


public sendValue(RowtoEmit:string){

this.RowSender.next(RowtoEmit);

}

public recieveValue():Observable<string>{
    return this.RowSender.asObservable();
}  
   
   
  constructor() { }
}
```

**Tier.Component.ts (this is the table component)**

```
constructor(private router: Router,private _EmitService :EmitService){}

//this the button for editing in table actions' column

edit(value : any)
    {
     this._EmitService.sendValue(value.id);
     this._EmitService.sendValue(value.raisonSociale);
     this._EmitService.sendValue(value.nomComplet);
     this._EmitService.sendValue(value.adresse);
     this.router.navigateByUrl('referencielcommun/Tier/Form');
    }
```

**Form.Component.ts**

```
 constructor(private _EmitService : EmitService) {

      this._EmitService.recieveValue().subscribe(
        (d:any)=>{
          {
          this.TierForm.controls['ID'].setValue(d.id);
          this.TierForm.controls['NomComplet'].setValue(d.raisonSociale ?? null);
          this.TierForm.controls['NomComplet'].setValue(d.nomComplet ?? null);
          this.TierForm.controls['Adresse'].setValue(d.adresse ?? null);
  
        }}); 
     }
```

**Form.component.html**

```
 <form [formGroup] ="TierForm" class="form-inline" (ngSubmit)="onFormSubmit()" >
      <fieldset>
      <legend>Formulaire de Tier</legend>
    
   <div class="container">
      <div class="row" >
        
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
          <div style="display: flex;flex-direction: column;">
            <mat-label><strong> Raison Sociale :</strong></mat-label>
            <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" appearance="fill">
              <input matInput ngModel formControlName="RaisonSociale">
              <mat-error *ngIf="true">
                Ce Champs est obligatoire.
              </mat-error>
            </mat-form-field>
          </div>
        </div>
      
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
        <div style="display: flex;flex-direction: column;">
          <mat-label><strong> Nom complet :    </strong> </mat-label>
          <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" appearance="fill">
            <input matInput ngModel formControlName="NomEtPrenom">
          </mat-form-field>
         </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
        <div style="display: flex;flex-direction: column;">
          <mat-label><strong> Adresse :    </strong> </mat-label>
          <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" appearance="fill">
            <input matInput ngModel formControlName="Adresse">
            <mat-error *ngIf="true">
              Ce Champs est obligatoire.
            </mat-error>
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>
      </div>
  
  <div class="center">
      <button class="addbutton" mat-raised-button color="primary" type="submit"  style="justify-content: left !important;">{{actionBtn}}</button>
      <button class="addbutton" mat-raised-button color="warn" (click)="Annuler()"  style="justify-content: left !important;">Annuler</button>
    </div>
     </fieldset>
    </form>
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I used BehaviorSubject in order to send a message and display it in another component, I tried to do the same thing with a row from Mat Table to a form, but i didn't implement that well, do you know any example for my case ? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now it is solved after starting from the begining.

First and foremost, we create an emitter service in order to send and receive data between two components.

**emit.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EmitService {

//we have to set an empty defaultValue for the TableRow
  public defaultValue : string = '';
  public TableRow : BehaviorSubject<string>= new BehaviorSubject<string>(this.defaultValue);


  public sendValue(RowtoEmit:string){
    this.TableRow.next(RowtoEmit);}

  public recieveValue():Observable<string>{
      return this.TableRow.asObservable();}  

  constructor() { }
}
```

And then we head to the Table component, that is of course from which we're going to send the data to the form component.

**table.component.ts**

```
// we declare the router and the Emit service in the constructor

  constructor(private router: Router,private _EmitService :EmitService){

// we add a method for the edit button on table

  edit(value : any)
    {

      this._EmitService.sendValue(value);
      this.router.navigateByUrl('referencielcommun/Tier/Form');
    }
}
```

Now we have to fetch the row data from our table with **(click)="edit(row)"**

**table.component.html**

```
 <ng-container matColumnDef="ACTION" >
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header class="actionheader"> Action</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
          
            <button mat-icon-button color="primary" type="button" (click)="edit(row)">
              <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
            </button>   
            </td>
          </ng-container>
```

then we head to our form component where we're going to receive our data and display them in the inputs.

**form.component.ts**

```
TierForm:any = this.formBuilder.group({
    ID:[0],
    RaisonSociale:[null,[Validators.required]],
    NomEtPrenom:[null],
    Adresse:[null,[Validators.required]],
  });

// we declare the router & the emit service as well in the constructor

constructor(private router : Router,private _EmitService : EmitService){

/* in the body of the constructor we set the values of the data recieved from 
our row in the form inputs*/


      this._EmitService.recieveValue().subscribe(
        (d:any)=>{
          if(d != null)
          {
          this.TierForm.get('ID').setValue(d.id ?? 0);
          this.TierForm.get('RaisonSociale').setValue(d.raisonSociale ?? null);
          this.TierForm.get('NomEtPrenom').setValue(d.nomEtPrenom ?? null);
          this.TierForm.get('Adresse').setValue(d.adresse ?? null);
        }}); 

}
```

**And finally** we put our formcontrols.

**form.component.html**

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
          <div style="display: flex;flex-direction: column;">
            <mat-label><strong> Raison Sociale :</strong></mat-label>
            <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" appearance="fill">
              <input matInput  [formControl]="TierForm.get('RaisonSociale')">
              <mat-error *ngIf="true">
                Ce Champs est obligatoire.
              </mat-error>
            </mat-form-field>
          </div>
        </div>
      
       <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
        <div style="display: flex;flex-direction: column;">
          <mat-label><strong> Nom complet :    </strong> </mat-label>
          <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" appearance="fill">
            <input matInput [formControl]="TierForm.get('NomEtPrenom')">
          </mat-form-field>
         </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
        <div style="display: flex;flex-direction: column;">
          <mat-label><strong> Adresse :    </strong> </mat-label>
          <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" appearance="fill">
            <input matInput  [formControl]="TierForm.get('Adresse')">
            <mat-error *ngIf="true">
              Ce Champs est obligatoire.
            </mat-error>
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>
      </div>
```

**Keep in mind that BehaviourSubject holds the value even if you navigate to another component, that's why you have to set the sent value to '' or null if you're done working with it.**

Answer (score 0):

You can try to fetch data in a method and then pass it to your custom component via service

Comment: Exactly, this is what i've done but it didn't work for me, can you provide an example, or a tutorial online that has this case please?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).